# Framework/Programming Language that uses "edit and test"-kind of development

Tags: software-development, web-development

Is there any server side programming framework/programming language implementation that support this kind of development (I don't know what is called):

1. start the server
2. edit the source code
3. test it on the browser, if error goto 2, the error line information (and if possible, the stack trace) should appear on the browser, and so on

So I don't have to restart the server at all, or go to the console/terminal to see the errors, I just need to alt-tab between the IDE/text editor and the browser only.

One example programming language that I found that support this kind of development process is PHP

Are there any other language that support this kind of development process (edit and test, without restart the server, and the error shown on browser)?

Comment: Yes you can do that with PHP (with the right settings). That being said - asI think you already knew that from your question - what is your question? Are you looking for a different server side language; if so tell us what features you need it to have as well as that one.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to put the question, are there any programming language that can things that described above?

Comment: Are you only interested in Web languages?
Or any programing languauge?
I'm thinking IPython works this way (with a web gui and all) for python

Comment: only server side web language ^^

Comment: Uhm.. Aren't all server side languages are like that?

Comment: @Seth, no. C++ isn't like that.

Comment: @PaulDraper Since when was C++ a server side language? Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: @Seth, since Google, eBay, and Amazon. (Facebook too...sort of, depending on how you consider HipHop.) C++ definitely isn't used by most programmers, though it is used in very high-load, enterprise situations. Wt is probably the most common C++ web toolkit. But, yes you are correct that most common languages/frameworks have auto-reloading (which I said in my answer below).

Comment: G-WAN, cpoll-cppsp, TreeFrog, Pt, CppCMS, ffead-cpp, standar CGI/FastCGI also a can be used make C++ a server side language

Answer (score 1):

[Node.js](http://nodejs.org) (I may be recommending Node.js altogether too much but I just love how awesomely multifunctional it is and power and yet super easy to do things).

Node.js is really actually quite perfect to build any size of website from basic hello-world website to high functioning web-app. I personally prefer PHP to it but that is a personal preference rather than based on any objective criteria I could name - I suppose two good ones would be that most hosts offer PHP whereas only a few offer Node.js, and if you are editing existing sites PHP is more important than Node.js because a lot more sites are in PHP than Node.js.

You can do everything by hand or to make life easier you can use a framework/plugin.  One good option is [Express](http://expressjs.com/) - and here is a tutorial on [basic site creation with Node.js & Express](http://shapeshed.com/creating-a-basic-site-with-node-and-express/). A more feature rich (or some could argue bloated if you aren't using the features) option would be [FlatIron](http://flatironjs.org/).

Node.js is compatible with pretty much any desktop operating system and also available via a [lot of OS package managers](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager).

Comment: I tried that link, after installing express using `sudo npm install -g express; express` completed, it shows: `bash: express: command not found`

Comment: hmm I don't know linux at all enough to comment on that; I ocassionally use linux but answering any linux operational questions not my knowledge area - hopefully someone else can help you there.

Answer (score 1):

I would call this "auto-reloading."

The language/framework will "reload" your code if it changes.

Just about any modern web framework will support this. Some big names:

- Anything PHP, as you have mentioned
- Ruby on Rails
- Python Django
- Play, Java or Scala

All of these will also give HTML with details errors/stacktraces for compilation errors and runtime errors.

You'll have to find some other feature to decide your language/framework; this feature is had by all.

Comment: While this might be answering the question somehow, we don't want just lists with "some big names" here, but high-quality recommendations – mentioning the pros and possible cons of the product, why you recommend it, and preferably your own experiences with it. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer, otherwise it might be removed.

Comment: @Izzy, as I said, almost every modern web framework supports in the OP's requested feature. "Mentioning the pros and possible cons...why you recommend it, and preferably your own experiences" for every web framework would be too much to cover in one answer. The OP will have to determine further criteria (performance, ease-of-use, portability, feature set, hosted environments, etc.) before receiving a meaningful recommendation, as the current requirement is far too broad. It's like asking "I am looking for a food which does not need to be refrigerated. Any recommendations?"

Comment: I agree with you on the facts, sure. Still, each SE site has its rules :) Why not pick the one you favor, go into details on that, and make this an answer/recommendation? Apart from that, I'd say the OP needs to add some more requirements to narrow things down...

Answer (score 0):

[Revel](http://revel.github.io/) for Go programming language

> Hot Code Reload
>
> Edit, save, and refresh. Revel compiles your code and templates for
>   you, so you don't miss a beat. Code doesn't compile? It gives you a
>   [helpful description](http://revel.github.io/img/CompilationError.png). Run-time code panic? Revel [has you covered](http://revel.github.io/img/Panic.png).